# Change the url entirely using Vue-router

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

My question is related to the Vue-router module in Vue. According to the docs, we can programmatically change only the last part of the current URL https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

So, the `$router.push` will only change the '3' part of this link:
`http://localhost:8080/#/1/2/3`

In my particular case, I want to reload the data, and dynamically change the WHOLE URL, like so:
`http://localhost:8080/#/1/2/3` -> `http://localhost:8080/#/5/6/7`

Setting a new `window.location.href` is on the table, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution. Is there an alternative to `$router.push`, but which will change the other parts of the URL too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue-router manages anything after the hashtag when it is in hash mode:

```
                      | HASH |
http://localhost:8080/#/1/2/3
```

Calling `$router.push(path: '3')` should set the url to `http://localhost:8080/#/3`

Regarding the hash in the Vue Router docs:

> The default mode for vue-router is **hash mode** - it uses the URL
>   hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when
>   the URL changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also push a non-relative URL:

Relative:

```js
$router.push(3)
$router.push({path: '3'}}
```

Absolute:

```
$router.push({path: '/5/6/7'})
```